# CopyPixels/MergeAlpha changes color AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, bitmapdata

I am making a smudge kind of tool. I use following method -

1) draw circle on a brushAlpha (bitmapData).

2)`_orignalData.copyPixels(_orignalData,
                                new Rectangle(oldMouseX, oldMouseY, diameter, diameter),
                                new Point(mouseX,mouseY), brushAlpha, new Point(0,0), true);`

This creates the required smudge effect but it also changes the color of pixels to primary colors (RGB) for example if a color of pixel is 0xFF8800 it will make it 0xFF0000 (red) or if the pixel color is 0x0088FF it will make it 0x0000FF

orignalData is a tranparent bitmapdata with initial color set 0x000000;

Is this effect is caused by mergealpha? 
please help

Edit-
I did some test i got these results-

backgroundColor = 0x00000000 , foregroundColor = 0xffdaff00
result = 0x00ff00 (Green)

backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF , foregroundColor = 0xffdaff00 
result = 0xFFFF00 (Yellow)

backgroundColor = 0xFF0000FF , foregroundColor = 0xffdaff00 
result = 0x00ff00 (Green) + when overdone it gets black

backgroundColor = 0xFF11FF88 , foregroundColor = 0xffdaff00 
result = 0x00ff00 (Green) + no black when over smudged

I tried some other colors also like

backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF , foregroundColor = 0xFF888800
result = 0x808000

backgroundColor = 0x0000000 , foregroundColor = 0xFF888800
result = 0x000000

can someone tell whats going on here?

Comment: Too lazy; see link: http://snipplr.com/view/17234/smudge/

Comment: I have seen that and my code is same as that of that link, Problem is not about the smudge. its working properly. The problem is that the color gets changed unexpectedly to primary colors